# What's the need for special exception classes?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, hierarchy

Why did the C++ standard bother inventing the `std::exception` classes? What's their benefit? My reason for asking is this:

```
try
{
  throw std::string("boom");
}
catch (std::string str)
{
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Works fine. Later, if I need, I can just make my own lightweight "exception" types. So why should I bother with `std::exception`?

Comment: please notice, that it is a good programming practice to capture exceptions by reference rather than by value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Why did the C++ standard bother inventing the `std::exception` classes? What's their benefit?**

It provides a generic and consistent interface to handle exceptions thrown by the standard library. All the exceptions generated by the standard library are inherited from `std::exception`.

Note that standard library api's can throw a number of different kinds of exceptions, To quote a few examples:

- `std::bad_alloc`
- `std::bad_cast`
- `std::bad_exception`
- `std::bad_typeid`
- `std::logic_error`
- `std::runtime_error`
- `std::bad_weak_ptr | C++11`
- `std::bad_function_call | C++11`
- `std::ios_base::failure | C++11`
- `std::bad_variant_access | C++17`

and so on...
`std::exception` is the base class for all these exceptions:

[image: exceptions hierarchy]

providing a base class for all these exceptions, allows you to handle multiple exceptions with a common exception handler.

---

**If I need, I can just make my own lightweight "exception" types. So why should I bother with `std::exception`?**

If you need your custom exception class go ahead and make one. But `std::exception` makes your job easier because it already provides a lot of functionality which a good exception class should have. It provides you the ease of deriving from it and overidding necessary functions(*in particular `std::exception::what()`*) for your class functionality.
This gives you 2 advantages the `std::exception` handler,

- can catch standard library exceptions as well as
- exceptions of the type of your custom exception class

<sup>Image courtesy: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception</sup>

Comment: I would argue that `what` is *not* an example of a good function though. I take exception (!) at the fact it returns a C-string. For god's sake, it's 2013!

Answer (score 6):

> **Why did the C++ standard bother inventing the std::exception classes? What's their benefit?**

Having different [kinds of exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/) allows you to catch specific **types** of errors.  Deriving exceptions from a common base allows for granularity in catching more generic or specific errors depending on circumstance.

In C++ an existing **type** system is already in place, so standardizing error strings was unnecessary when you can explicitly create an exception of a desired type in the language.

***std::exception*** and its derived classes exist for two main reasons:

1. The standard library has to have some kind of exception hierarchy to
   throw in exceptional circumstances.  It would be inappropriate to
   always throw an **std::string** because you would have no clean way to
   target specific kinds of errors.
2. To provide an extensible class based interface for library vendors to throw the most basic error types and provide a common fallback for users.  You may want to provide more error metadata than a simple **what()** string so that the person catching your error can more intelligently recover from it.

   At the same time **std::exception** as a common base allows a general catchall less all-encompassing than **...** if the user only cares about that error message.

If all you ever do is print and quit then it doesn't really matter, but you may as well use **std::runtime_error** which inherits from **std::exception** for catch convenience.

> **Later, if I need, I can just make my own lightweight "exception" types. So why should I bother with std::exception?**

If you inherit from **std::runtime_error** and use your own custom error type then you can retroactively add error metadata without having to rewrite catch blocks!  In contrast, if you ever changed your error handling design then you would be forced to rewrite all your **std::string** catches because you cannot safely inherit from **std::string**.  It is not a forward-looking design decision.

If that doesn't seem so bad right now, imagine if your code were to become shared across multiple projects as a shared library with various programmers working on it.  Migrating to the new version of your library would become a pain.

This isn't even mentioning that std::string can throw its own exceptions during copy, construction, or access of characters!

Boost's website has some good guidelines in exception handling and class construction [here](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html).

## User Story

> I am writing some network code and using a third party vendor's
>   library.  On an invalid ip address being entered by the user this
>   library throws a custom exception **nw::invalid_ip** derived from 
>   **std::runtime_error**. **nw::invalid_ip** contains a **what()** describing
>   the error message, but also the **incorrect_ip()** address supplied.
>
> I also use **std::vector** to store sockets, and am making use of the
>   checked **at()** call to safely access indices.  I know that if I
>   call **at()** on a value out of bounds **std::out_of_range** is thrown.
>
> I know other things may be thrown as well, but I do not know how to
>   handle them, or what exactly they might be.
>
> When I get an **nw::invalid_ip** error I pop up a modal with an input
>   box for the user populated with the invalid ip address so they can edit
>   it and try again.
>
> For **std::out_of_range** issues, I respond by running an integrity check
>   on the sockets and fixing the vector/socket relationship that has fallen
>   out of synch.
>
> For any other **std::exception** issues I terminate the program with an
>   error log. Finally I have a **catch(...)** which logs "unknown error!" and
>   terminates.
>
> It would be difficult to robustly do this with only **std::string** being thrown.

Here's a basic example of a few things being thrown in different cases so you can play with catching exceptions.

## ExampleExceptions.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

struct Base1 {
    virtual ~Base1(){}
};
struct Base2 {
    virtual ~Base2(){}
};

class Class1 : public Base1 {};
class Class2 : public Base2 {};

class CustomException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    explicit CustomException(const std::string& what_arg, int errorCode):
        std::runtime_error(what_arg),
        errorCode(errorCode){
    }
    int whatErrorCode() const {
        return errorCode;
    }
private:
    int errorCode;
};

void tryWrap(typename std::function<void()> f){
    try {
        f();
    } catch(CustomException &e) {
        std::cout << "Custom Exception: " << e.what() << " Error Code: " << e.whatErrorCode() << std::endl;
    } catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
        std::cout << "Range exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(std::bad_cast &e) {
        std::cout << "Cast exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "General exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "What just happened?" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Class1 a;
    Class2 b;

    std::vector<Class2> values;

    tryWrap([](){
        throw CustomException("My exception with an additional error code!", 42);
    });

    tryWrap([&](){
        values.at(10);
    });

    tryWrap([&](){
        Class2 c = dynamic_cast<Class2&>(a);
    });

    tryWrap([&](){
        values.push_back(dynamic_cast<Class2&>(a));
        values.at(1);
    });

    tryWrap([](){
        std::bitset<5> mybitset (std::string("01234"));
    });

    tryWrap([](){
        throw 5;
    });
}
```

## Output:

```
Custom Exception: My exception with an additional error code! Error Code: 42
Range exception: vector::_M_range_check
Cast exception: std::bad_cast
Cast exception: std::bad_cast
General exception: bitset::_M_copy_from_ptr
What just happened?
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a legitimate question because `std::exception` only really contains a single property: `what()`, a `string`. So it's tempting to just use `string` instead of `exception`. But the fact is that an `exception` is not a `string`. If you treat an exception like it's merely a `string`, you lose the ability to derive from it in specialized exception classes that would provide more properties.

For example today you throw `string`s in your own code. Tomorrow you decide to add more properties to certain cases like a database connection exception. You can't just derive from `string` to make this change; you will need to write a new exception class and change all the exception handlers for `string`. Using `exception` is a way for exception handlers to use only the data they care about, to pick and choose exceptions as they need to handle them.

Also if you throw and handle only `string`-typed exceptions, you will miss all exceptions thrown from any code that's not your own. If this distinction is intentional, it would be best described by using a common exception class to signify this, not the generic type of `string`.

`exception` is also more specific than `string`. This means library developers can write functions that accept exceptions as parameters, which is clearer than accepting a `string`.

All of this is essentially free, just use `exception` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because something "works fine" in a 6 line toy example doesn't mean it is scalable or maintainable in real code.

Consider this function:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convert(const T& t)
{
    return boost:lexical_cast<std::string>(t);
}
```

This could throw `bad_alloc` if memory for the string cannot be allocated, or could throw  `bad_cast` if the conversion fails.

A caller of this function might want to handle the failed conversion case which indicates bad input but isn't a fatal error, but not want to handle the out-of-memory case, because they can't do anything about it so let the exception propagate up the stack. This is very easy to do in C++, for example:

```
std::string s;
try {
  s = convert(val);
} catch (const std::bad_cast& e) {
  s = "failed";
}
```

If exceptions were just thrown as `std::string` the code would have to be:

```
std::string s;
try {
  s = convert(val);
} catch (const std::string& e) {
  if (e.find("bad_cast") != std::string::npos)
    s = "failed";
  else
    throw;
}
```

This takes more code to implement and relies on the exact wording of the exception string, which might depend on the compiler implementation and the definition of `boost::lexical_cast`.  If every piece of exception handling in the system had to do string comparisons to decide if the error can be handled at that point it would be messy and unmaintainable. A small change to the spelling of an exception message in one part of the system that throws exceptions might cause the exception handling code in another part of the system to stop working. This creates tight coupling between the location of an error and *every* bit of error handling code in the system. One of the advantages of using exceptions is to allow error handling to be separated from the main logic, you lose that advantage if you create dependencies based on string comparisons across the whole system.

Exception handling in C++ catches things by matching on the exception's type, it doesn't catch by matching on an exception's value, so it makes sense to throw things of different types to allow fine-grained handling. Throwing things of a single string type and handling them based on the string's value is messy, non-portable and more difficult.

> Later, if I need, I can just make my own lightweight "exception" types. So why should I bother with std::exception?

If your code is useful and reusable and I want to use it in part of my system, do I have to add exception handling that catches all your lightweight types?  Why should the whole of my system care about the internal details of a library that one bit of the system relies on?  If your custom exception types are derived from `std::exception` then I can catch them by `const std::exception&` without knowing (or caring) about the specific types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only user of the class,you can avoid `std::exception`(*if you want to avoid the standard library exceptions*)

---

But if your class is going to be used by others (*programmers*),how would they handle the exception.

If your class `throws` a `string` that describes the **error**,that would not help since the consumers of your class would prefer a more **standard** way(*catch an exception object and query it's what method*) to handle the `exception` rather than catching a string..

Also you can catch exceptions thrown by the standard library by catching an `exception` object

---

You can override the `what` method of [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/) class to give more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm surprised no one mentioned this:

1. You need multiple types of exceptions in order to be able to distinguish them -- some kinds of exceptions should be handled, while others shouldn't.
2. They need to have a common base class to allow you to have a means for displaying a sane message to the user without having to know *all* the types of exceptions that your program could possibly throw (which is impossible when using external closed source libraries).